# How to conditionally modify a list with python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
bigdumblist = [(0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 237}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 1, 'product_uom_qty': 1})]
```

I want the list to be modified as such

```
# ***pseudocode*** 
if 'product_id' ==2 change to 3 if 'product_uom_qty' >= 45 divide by 45
```

new list

```
bigdumblist = [((0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 5})), (0, 0, {'product_id': 1, 'product_uom_qty': 1})]
```

I have tried to research but have found a way to change the values of certain items on the list. I know I can use indexing to access the list but is there a way to access items on the list based on the items themselves?

Comment: You have to iterate through the list, maybe with a list comprehension.

Comment: In this case, changing the value by index is the cleanest way to solve the problem, probably. A list comprehension would _work_, but it would be ugly.

Comment: Where did `(0, 0, {'product_id': 1, 'product_uom_qty': 1})` go?

Comment: This sounds like a very unusual and specific requirement. Are you sure that is what you want? Also, it's not clear how you went from two tuples to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through the list! Below is Python code that does just that:

```
bigdumblist = [(0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 237}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 1, 'product_uom_qty': 1})]
for tup in bigdumblist:
    # Iterates through the tuples in bigdumblist
    for item in tup:
        # Checks if the item in the tuple is a dictionary
        if type(item) == dict:
            # Does specified changes to the dictionary
            if item["product_id"] == 2:
                item["product_id"] = 3
            
            if item["product_uom_qty"] >= 45:
                item["product_uom_qty"] /= 45
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking about it as a list, it's easier to think of what you want to do with a single item.

```
def repair_item(item):
    if item["product_id"] == 2:
        item["product_id"] = 3
    if item["product_uom_qty"] >= 45:
        item["product_uom_qty"] /= 45
```

Now, simply loop over all the items:

```
for _, _, item in my_list:
    repair_item(item)
```